Money stuck, wallet wont sign tx or allow me to get keys
I just opened a new wallet using phantom. Depositing some money to buy a coin, went on raydium, error. tried on jup, error. when i realized it wasnt allowing any transactions to go through citing "error signing transaction" I tried swapping some sol to usdt and that failed so i went to get my keys in order to reinstall phantom wallet and when i put the password the page stays empty. when i try to send the funds to another wallet it says "unable to send" help please. im feeling like i got honeypotted by phantom wallet.

Just noticed when I restart my browser and input the password it says an error has occurred and doesnt advance, if I click out of it and click the phantom shortcut again it appears I'm signed in.
